# A reliable way to disable/block contract creation when using eth_sendRawTransaction

Tags: raw-transaction

I am looking for a reliable way to disable/block contract creation when using eth_sendRawTransaction via the JSON RPC. Do you think it is possible without changing the source code of geth/parity/ethereumj?

Looking at the other similar questions, I understand that the field to: should be null for a transaction to be considered contractCreate. However, when an HD wallet sends a raw transaction via the REST RPC there is a single field data: which contains only bytecode and no to: field. My idea is to limit contract creation on the network level and I am looking for a pattern in the data byte array or a decoding function that can let me guess the transaction type directly from the data: value.

Thank you for your suggestions!